# Сортировка xml-объекта по тегу в ms sql server

Tags: sql-server

Как сделать сортировку данных таблицы MS SQL в колонке типа XML,
чтобы все теги шли в алфавитном порядке (по названию тега)?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно рассматривать xml как строку:

```
select *
from #t
order by cast(dxml as nvarchar(max))
```

Можно использовать имя тега:

```
select *
from #t
order by dxml.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'nvarchar(max)')
```